# fetch data using count function in django

Tags: python, database, django, error-handling

am trying to fech data from database using count function in django, whenever i try this code using tablename.objects.count() than its working fine. ehan i try this :-

views.py:-

```
def home(request):
    getsessionuserid = request.session['getuser_id']
    getlatestproject = jobs.objects.all()
    getcountvalues = applicationform.objects.count(user_id=getsessionuserid)    
    getinterviewcount = interview.objects.count()   
    getjobscount = jobs.objects.count()
    return render_to_response(
    'home.html',
    { 'user': request.user, 'getlatestproject': getlatestproject , 'getcountvalues': getcountvalues, 'getinterviewcount': getinterviewcount , 'getjobscount': getjobscount }
    )
```

than it display an error:-

count() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id'

i want to count data in condition where user_id=getsessionuserid but it dispaly error.

Comment: I strongly recommend you use the [Django authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) system instead of keeping track of user ids in the session by yourself.

Comment: And I strongly recommend you use some underscores in your variable names, to make them easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count()` method does not take any arguments. You can filter the queryset first, then use count. For example:

```
published_count = Book.objects.filter(published=True).count()
```